# read an image I just wrote in android

Tags: android, image, file-io

So, largely for debugging purposes, I want to be able to write an image at arbitrary points in my code, and look at it later. I figured this would be easiest if I just wrote a my bitmap to a file and read it back later, but I cannot seem to figure out where to find the file after I write it, or how to open an image that is not in res/drawable with a corresponding handle in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `openFileOutput()` and `openFileInput()`.  These pull up data streams that point to files in your app's directory, and are (as far as I know), the suggested way to handle files that your app makes.